# How to configure orientdb to only allow access over local network

Tags: orientdb

I can currently access my orientdb server from a remote network. I wish to restrict access to local network (alternatively just the machine running the server instance) only. Can't figure out how to do it without using the os firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `127.0.0.1` instead of `0.0.0.0` in `$ORIENTDB/config/orientdb-server-config.xml` file.